# Class Casting in MooTools?

Tags: javascript, class, casting, mootools

I have a class and two other classes extending it. I essentially want to be able to make an object of the main class and then be able to convert/cast it into the appropriate subclass depending on some conditions of the object itself. Alternatively, I could replace the instance of the main class with an instance of the subclass. Are either of these possible in MooTools? Is there an alternative way to tackle this situation that I'm missing? Should I give up on using subclasses?

Answer (score 0):

Could you be a bit more specific on what you're trying to do? At least I don't see a way to extend an object without overwriting conflicting properties, so you might need to think of another approach.